# Linq2Db and string.join()

Tags: c#, linq2db

I am using Linq2db in my big query with subqueries.
At the one place inside it, I want to use string.Join():

```
...
FullPath = string.Join(" -> ", GetPathQuery(db, c.Id).Select(pi => pi.Name))
...
```

But I have received an exception:

> LinqException: 'Join(" -> ", value(RI.DAL.Categories.AdminCategoryPreviewDAL).GetPathQuery(value(RI.DAL.Categories.AdminCategoryPreviewDAL+<>c__DisplayClass4_0).db, c.Id).Select(pi => pi.Name))' cannot be converted to SQL.

I use Postgre SQL and it has the `concat_ws` function which is perfect for me. So I try to use it:

```
[Sql.Expression("concat_ws({1}, {0})")]
public static string JoinAsString(this IQueryable<string> query, string separator)
{
    return string.Join(separator, query);
}

...
FullPath = GetPathQuery(db, c.Id).Select(pi => pi.Name).JoinAsString(" -> ")
...
```

But I was failed with the same exception.

---

The full source code of the GetPathQuery:

```
    private IQueryable<CategoryPathItemCte> GetPathQuery(IStoreDb db, Guid categoryId)
    {
        var categoryPathCte = db.GetCte<CategoryPathItemCte>(categoryHierarchy =>
        {
            return
                (
                    from c in db.Categories
                    where c.Id == categoryId
                    select new CategoryPathItemCte
                    {
                        CategoryId = c.Id,
                        ParentCategoryId = c.ParentId,
                        Name = c.Name,
                        SeoUrlName = c.SeoUrlName
                    }
                )
                .Concat
                (
                    from c in db.Categories
                    from eh in categoryHierarchy.InnerJoin(ch => ch.ParentCategoryId == c.Id)
                    select new CategoryPathItemCte
                    {
                        CategoryId = c.Id,
                        ParentCategoryId = c.ParentId,
                        Name = c.Name,
                        SeoUrlName = c.SeoUrlName
                    }
                );
        });

        return categoryPathCte;
    }
```

Comment: Could you provide source code for `GetPathQuery` method?

Comment: Of course - I I have added it into the post body.

Answer (score 1):

can you try like this,

```
FullPath = string.Join(" -> ", GetPathQuery(db, c.Id).Select(pi => pi.Name).ToList());
```

More query friendly approach

```
GetPathQuery(db, c.Id).Select(pi => pi.Name)
   .Aggregate(string.Empty, (results, nextString) 
               => string.Format("{0} -> {1}", results, nextString));
```

Comment: It is not a good idea. If I get you right - one SQL query will be split into several queries + C# code. I think there will be performance degradation.

Comment: I have added another alternative can you check ?

Comment: I have replaced "string.Format" with plain concatenation like this: "results + " -> " + nextString" because linq2db can't work with string.format.
The problem is it is strange but it still doesn't work:    
LinqException: Sequence 'value(RI.DAL.Categories.AdminCategoryPreviewDAL).GetPathQuery(value(RI.DAL.Categories.AdminCategoryPreviewDAL+<>c__DisplayClass4_0).db, c.Id).Select(pi => pi.Name).Aggregate(String.Empty, (results, nextString) => ((results + " -> ") + nextString))' cannot be converted to SQL.

Comment: My full code is:  
FullPath = GetPathQuery(db, c.Id).Select(pi => pi.Name)
                        .Aggregate(string.Empty, (results, nextString) => results + " -> " + nextString)

Comment: can you try with simple select + aggreate? I would like to see whether the problem is related with aggregation or not

Comment: looks like the problem is not in select or aggregate.
It is in the GetPathQuery calling! Linq2Db try to parse the GetPathQuery method like some SQL statement. Looks like I have to inline code from GetPathQuery method into the main query.

Comment: So I have solved the problem with GetPathQuery with the big performance decline. Now I am able to do something like this: pathQuery.Where(c1 => c1.RootCategoryId == c.Id).Select(c1 => c1.Name).FirstOrDefault(). But the Aggregation still produce the exception of "... cannot be converted to SQL".